# Calculate the cosine similarity between two probability measures, rather then between two vectors

Tags: probability, distributions, similarities, measure-theory, cosine-similarity

**Introduction.** The [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) is often calculated among two vectors, i.e. $C_S(X,Y)$:
\begin{equation}
C_S(X,Y) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i,Y_i)}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}^{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_{i}^{2}}}
\end{equation}

**Question.** Would it make sense to calculate the cosine similarity between two probability measures, $P$ and $Q$, on a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$, i.e. $C_S(P,Q)$? If Yes, would it be sufficient to use the above mentioned equation for $C_S(X,Y)$ and maybe just writing something like $X \sim P$ and $Y \sim Q$?